# Can't access function from VC controller - can't use type on instance

Tags: ios, xcode, function, swift4

Im creating a form with an image uploader to firebase using an ImagePickerController. I'm trying to create a function to upload a photo to firebase and store the uid to the relevant database.

I'm having some issues with using/accessing the functions.

**Compile errors:** 
- Instance member 'uploadImageToFirebaseAndReturnImageURL' cannot be used on type 'DataService'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
- Instance member 'updateUserWithProfileImageURL' cannot be used on type 'DataService'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

The code is structured in Controller: "createActivityVC" , Services: "DataService", Extension: "ImageUploader"

**createActivityVC:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class createActivityVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func addPictureBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {

     imagePicker()
}

}
```

**Extension: ImageUploader**

```
 import UIKit

 extension createActivityVC: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,      UINavigationControllerDelegate{

func imagePicker() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
    }
    if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
    }

    let uid = DataService.uploadImageToFirebaseAndReturnImageURL("profileimage", selectedImageFromPicker)
    DataService.updateUserWithProfileImageURL()
}


func imagePickerCancelBtnWasPressed(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    print("Picker cancel button clicked")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

**Services: DataService**

```
 import Foundation
 import Firebase

 let DB_BASE = Database.database().reference() // gets the database URL from Firebase
 let storage = Storage.storage() // Get a reference to the storage service using the default Firebase App
 let DB_STORE = storage.reference() // Create a storage reference from our storage service

class DataService {
static let instance = DataService()

// static is used to make it a singleton class - meaning it is accessible to all other class

private var _REF_BASE = DB_BASE
private var _REF_USERS = DB_BASE.child("users")
private var _REF_CLUBS = DB_BASE.child("clubs")
private var _REF_ACTIVITY = DB_BASE.child("activities")
private var _REF_PROFILEIMAGES = DB_STORE.child("profileimages")
private var _REF_MEDIA = DB_STORE.child("media")

var REF_BASE: DatabaseReference {
    return _REF_BASE
}

var REF_USERS: DatabaseReference {
    return _REF_USERS
}

var REF_CLUBS: DatabaseReference {
    return _REF_CLUBS
}

var REF_ACTIVITY: DatabaseReference {
    return _REF_ACTIVITY
}

var REF_PROFILEIMAGES: StorageReference {
    return _REF_PROFILEIMAGES
}

var REF_MEDIA: StorageReference {
    return _REF_MEDIA
}




func uploadImageToFirebaseAndReturnImageURL(directory: String, image: UIImage!, handler: @escaping(_ imageURL: (ImageURL))  -> ()) {
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString // create unique image name

    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        DB_STORE.child(directory).putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            if let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                let d = ImageURL(imageURL: profileImageUrl)
                handler (d)


            }
            return

        })
    }



}

func updateUserWithProfileImageURL(uid: String, imageURL: String){
    REF_USERS.child(uid).child("profileImage").setValue(imageURL)
}




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kqtr explained what was wrong with your code, but didn't go into detail about WHY it was wrong. Here is a more thorough explanation:

Your `DataService` class is set up as a singleton: An object that gets created once and only once.

The syntax `DataService.someMethod()` is for invoking a type method - a method that is implemented by the class itself, not by some instance of the class. (I prefer the name "class method" but Apple's docs call it a "type method".)

In that case your method would be declared

`class func uploadImageToFirebaseAndReturnImageURL()`

However, your function is an instance function. It is a message to some instance of your `DataService` class.

Since `DataService` is a singleton, and you have a static var `instance` to refer to your singleton, you need to change your code to read `DataService.instance.uploadImageToFirebaseAndReturnImageURL()`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call your shared instance. Corrected version:

```
DataService.instance.uploadImageToFirebaseAndReturnImageURL(...
```

Take some time to read the error again and make sure you understanding it: 
it will greatly help you next time you encounter it!